# Opacity effect for the backcover

Tags: tikz-pgf

Here is a paragraph aimed to put at the back cover of a book. I want to have opacity effect for this because it is placed on top of a background picture of the back cover. How can I add opacity effect to the paragraph? 
[image: picture on top of back cover]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[text width=12cm,align=left] {\noindent\fcolorbox{black}{cyan!22}{%
\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr1.00733\textwidth-2\fboxrule-2\fboxsep\relax}

\thispagestyle{empty}



\textcopyright{} 2009 $-$ 2018 David Nguyen \\
All rights reserved.

    This work is not to be  distributed and/or modified without licensse.


This content has been tailored by the author over his years of training the best mathematical minds. Problems in the booklet provides a wide array of mathematics flavours, enhance problem solving and thinking ways for young learners.

\begin{center}
 99 32 11 88 48 01\hspace{2em}9 9 8 6 5 4 %1 
\end{center}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
First edition:  & May 2010 \\
Second impression, with minor extensions & January 2011 \\
Third impression, with minor extensions & May 2016 
\end{tabular}
\end{center}


Institute of Mathematics\\
Vietnam \\




\end{minipage}}};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following is a `tcolorbox` solution which allows to set the required margins directly. I marked the options inside the code:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[skins]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}%
\begin{tcolorbox}[
  enhanced,size=minimal,sharp corners,
  text fill,            % only, if \vfill is to be used
  width       = 210mm,  % paper width
  height      = 297mm,  % paper height
  leftrule    = 20mm,   % outer margin
  rightrule   = 20mm,   % outer margin
  toprule     = 25mm,   % outer margin
  bottomrule  = 25mm,   % outer margin
  left        = 15mm,   % inner margin
  right       = 15mm,   % inner margin
  top         = 20mm,   % inner margin
  bottom      = 20mm,   % inner margin
  frame style = {fill overzoom image=goldshade.png},  % background image
  opacityback = 0.5,    % transparency
  colback     = cyan!22,
]

\textcopyright{} 2009 $-$ 2018 David Nguyen \\
All rights reserved.

    This work is not to be  distributed and/or modified without licensse.

This content has been tailored by the author over his years of training the best mathematical minds. Problems in the booklet provides a wide array of mathematics flavours, enhance problem solving and thinking ways for young learners.

\vfill

\begin{center}
 99 32 11 88 48 01\hspace{2em}9 9 8 6 5 4 %1
\end{center}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
First edition:  & May 2010 \\
Second impression, with minor extensions & January 2011 \\
Third impression, with minor extensions & May 2016
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

Institute of Mathematics\\
Vietnam

\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update:**

The original question used the `standalone` class. With some small modifications, you can get the same thing as page using a class like `article`.

The following example also contains

`frame style = {fill plain image*={scale=3}{goldshade.png}}`

to show the inclusion of a background image with arbitraty scaling as the OP asked for in comments.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[skins,breakable]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{mathrsfs,lipsum}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-20]

\begin{tcolorbox}[
  enhanced,size=minimal,sharp corners,
  spread,
  phantom=\thispagestyle{empty},
  text fill,            % only, if \vfill is to be used
  leftrule    = 20mm,   % outer margin
  rightrule   = 20mm,   % outer margin
  toprule     = 25mm,   % outer margin
  bottomrule  = 25mm,   % outer margin
  left        = 15mm,   % inner margin
  right       = 15mm,   % inner margin
  top         = 20mm,   % inner margin
  bottom      = 20mm,   % inner margin
  frame style = {fill plain image*={scale=3}{goldshade.png}},  % background image
  opacityback = 0.5,    % transparency
  colback     = cyan!22,
]
%

\textcopyright{} 2009 $-$ 2018 David Nguyen \\
All rights reserved.

    This work is not to be  distributed and/or modified without licensse.

This content has been tailored by the author over his years of training the best mathematical minds. Problems in the booklet provides a wide array of mathematics flavours, enhance problem solving and thinking ways for young learners.

\vfill

\begin{center}
 99 32 11 88 48 01\hspace{2em}9 9 8 6 5 4 %1
\end{center}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
First edition:  & May 2010 \\
Second impression, with minor extensions & January 2011 \\
Third impression, with minor extensions & May 2016
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

Institute of Mathematics\\
Vietnam

\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

Comment: How can I increase the size of the frame image in frame style = {fill overzoom image=goldshade.png} (because my pdf image is not large enough to cover the four corners?

Comment: @Thumbolt Have you tried? The `fill overzoom image` option always enlarges the image to fill the whole frame...

Comment: @Thumbolt If your pdf image contains white borders, you can select the real content part with a ``viewport` selection, e.g. `frame style = {fill overzoom image*={viewport=1cm 1cm 10cm 10cm}{mypicture.pdf}}`. The `viewport` parameters depend on your image...

Comment: I have a penrose background from this site for this and tried. It would be fit if it is 25% larger. Anyway, another problem turns up when the document is not standalone format. Perhaps, I need to put new question.

Comment: @Thumbolt I updated the answer to show arbitrary scaling and usage without `standalone`.

Comment: The updated version works well now. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

You can apply an `opacity=` to the text:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{showframe}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[anchor=south,inner sep=0] (A) at (0,0) 
    {\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{../images/EiffelWide.jpg}};

\node[text width=10cm,align=left, anchor=south, text opacity=0.9, 
    shift={(0.0cm,0.75cm)}
] at (0,0) 
{\noindent\fcolorbox{black}{cyan!22}{%
\begin{minipage}{10.0cm}

\thispagestyle{empty}

\textcopyright{} 2009 $-$ 2018 David Nguyen

All rights reserved.

This work is not to be  distributed and/or modified without licensee.

This content has been tailored by the author over his years of training the best mathematical minds. Problems in the booklet provides a wide array of mathematics flavours, enhance problem solving and thinking ways for young learners.

\begin{center}
 99 32 11 88 48 01\hspace{2em}9 9 8 6 5 4 %1 
\end{center}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
    First edition:  & May 2010 \\
    Second impression, with minor extensions & January 2011 \\
    Third impression, with minor extensions & May 2016 
\end{tabular}
\end{center}


Institute of Mathematics

Vietnam 
\end{minipage}}};

\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: Does this way allow the wider four margins?

Comment: @Thumbolt: Of course. Its usign `tikz` so you have the `tikz` controls.

Comment: So how? I use the inner sep but it is not useful \node[text width=12cm,align=left,fill opacity=0.7, inner sep=4cm]

Comment: @Thumbolt: I modified it to show you one way to do this. You can adjust the location of the `minipage` and change its dimensions to tweak it.

Answer (score 3):

Very similar to Peter Grill's nice answer, just with `fill opacity`. The tcolorbox will inherit the fill opacity of the node.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[rotate=90] {\includegraphics[scale=1.5]{example-image-a}};
\node[text width=12cm,align=left,fill opacity=0.7] {\noindent\fcolorbox{black}{cyan!22}{%
\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr1.00733\textwidth-2\fboxrule-2\fboxsep\relax}

\vspace*{4cm}


\textcopyright{} 2009 $-$ 2018 David Nguyen \\
All rights reserved.

    This work is not to be  distributed and/or modified without licensse.


This content has been tailored by the author over his years of training the best mathematical minds. Problems in the booklet provides a wide array of mathematics flavours, enhance problem solving and thinking ways for young learners.

\begin{center}
 99 32 11 88 48 01\hspace{2em}9 9 8 6 5 4 %1 
\end{center}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
First edition:  & May 2010 \\
Second impression, with minor extensions & January 2011 \\
Third impression, with minor extensions & May 2016 
\end{tabular}
\end{center}


Institute of Mathematics\\
Vietnam \\


\vspace*{4cm}

\end{minipage}}};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you increase the margin of the cyan color background?

Comment: @Thumbolt Sure, I made an update.

Comment: It just works for the top margin and bottom margin. The left and right margins are not wide enough.